# cohomology of delta complexes

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I am reading algebraic topology by Allen Hatcher, in page  188, in the chapter "cohomology" the last paragraph reads

> The condition $\delta \psi=0$  has an interpretation of a more geometric nature when $X$ is a surface and the group $G$ is $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Z}_2$.  Consider first the simpler case $G = \mathbb{Z}_2$.[image] The
> condition  $\delta \psi=0$ means that the number of times that $\psi$ takes the value 1 on the
> edges of each 2 simplex is even, either 0 or 2. This means we can associate to $\psi$ a
> collection $C_\psi$ of disjoint curves in $X$ crossing the
> 1 skeleton transversely, such that the number of
> intersections of $C_\psi$ with each edge is equal to the
> value of $\psi$ on that edge. If $\psi=\delta \varphi$ for some $\varphi$,
> then the curves of $C_\psi$ divide $X$ into two regions
> $X_0$ and $X_1$ where the subscript indicates the value
> of $\varphi$ on all vertices in the region.

I have the following questions,

1. Does the function $\psi$ has specified already? if yes, how the values of each edge under $\psi$ has been assigned.
2. the last sentence states that each level curve deivide $X$ into two regions, are they there any significance in that? as i tend to think it is trivial if we draw a closed loop in a space, it would divide the space into part inside the loop and part outside the loop(please correct me if my intuition is wrong)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question 1, this passage starts with the phrase:

> *The condition $\delta\psi = 0$ has an interpretation...*.

As commonly happens in mathematical writing, in this phrase there is a hidden universal quantifier:

> *[For every $1$-cocycle $\psi$ of the triangulated surface $S$, with coefficients in $G$] the condition $\delta\psi = 0$ has an interpretation...*

So $\psi$ is indeed assumed to be given, hence all of its individual values on every individual edge are also assumed to be given.

---

Regarding question 2 about the last sentence, keep in mind that this sentence starts with a condition:

> *If $\psi = \delta\phi$ for some $\phi$...*

In order to understand this last sentence, you must first ask yourself: what kind of object is $\phi$? From the context of the equation $\psi = \delta\phi$, clearly $\phi$ is a $0$-cocycle of the triangulated surface with coefficients in $\mathbb Z_2$. Representing the two elements of $\mathbb Z_2$ as $\{0,1\}$, for each $0$-simplex $v$ it follows that $\phi(v) \in \{0,1\}$.

The gray area in the picture, which Hatcher denotes $X_1$, depicts the set of $0$-simplices $v$ such that $\phi(v)=1$, together with portions of $1$-simplices and $2$-simplices that are adjacent to any such $0$-simplex $v$. The white area denoted $X_0$ is a similar depiction with $\phi(v)=0$.

To challenge your intuition, I'm sure you can imagine a surface $S$ and a simple closed curve on $S$ that does *not* divide $S$ into two pieces; think of the torus, for example. On such a surface, if that loop were associated to a 1-dimensional cocycle $\psi$ with $\mathbb Z_2$ coefficients, it would follow that there *does not exist* any $0$-dimensional cocycle $\phi$ with $\mathbb Z_2$ coefficients such that $\psi = \delta\phi$.

Comment: What is the significance of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ here?What happens if I choose another coefficient group, say $\mathbb{Z}$ ?

Comment: For one, $\mathbb Z_2$ has two elements. That leaves you free to depict them in two colors, say, as white and gray in the  picture you copied from Hatcher's book.

Comment: There is mathematical significance also. Not every manifold is orientable over $\mathbb Z$, but *every* manifold is orientable over $\mathbb Z_2$. If you don't know this already, you'll learn it when studying Poincaré duality: these two properties are distinguished by the behavior of cohomology with $\mathbb Z$ coefficients versus cohomology with $\mathbb Z_2$ coefficients.

Comment: what about $\mathbb{Z}_3$, does all the argument stay if we take $\mathbb{Z}_3$ or in general $\mathbb{Z}_n$ instead of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ as the coeffificent group?

Comment: I'm not sure which argument you are asking about, but the discussion of Hatcher's picture --- with its "2-coloring" using the colors white and gray --- depends heavily on the fact that $\mathbb Z_2$ has 2 elements.